# I need help with Demidovich's 2606 task

Tags: calculus, analysis

Good day!
Task from Demidovich № 2606:

Prove that if for a positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ the condition

$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n}), \ \ n \to \infty$

is satisfished, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$

$a_n = o(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-\varepsilon}}), \ n \to \infty$

and if $\alpha > 0$, then sequence $\{a_n\}$, start with some number, decreasing, tends to 0.

It is necessary to solve this problem, but I do not understand at all how(
Can you please suggest an approximate path, where to go?

Comment: Assume that there is no error in the recursion, i.e. $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac{\alpha}{n},$$ how would you proceed then?

Comment: @severin, Sorry for  misleading you. There is not recursion.  $\{a_n\}$ - is sequence ( or infinity series ). $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n}), \ \ n \to \infty$ - is condition.

Comment: Yes, I got that :) still this implies that those numbers satisfy a recursion.